# Why does the map.insert() method invoke the copy constructor twice?

Tags: c++, dictionary, copy-constructor

I'm creating the custom class `Node` in order to implement a binary tree using a `map<int,Node>` container: the `int` key of the map is the identifier of a `Node` object. In the class `Node` I had to implement a copy constructor.

When inserting a `Node` object on the map, I noticed that the copy constructor of the `Node` is invoked twice. Why?

```
cout << "node2" << endl;
Node node2;
node2.set_depth(2);
node2.make_it_branch(3,4);

cout << "map" << endl;
map<int,Node> mapping;
cout << "toInsert" << endl;
pair<int,Node> toInsert = pair<int,Node>(2,node2);
cout << "insert" << endl;
mapping.insert(toInsert);
```

Running the above code, the output is as follows:

```
node2
--- Node()
map
toInsert
--- Node(const Node& orig)
insert
--- Node(const Node& orig)   // Why does the copy constructor be invoked twice?
--- Node(const Node& orig)   // ------------------------------------------------
--- ~Node()
--- ~Node()
--- ~Node()
--- ~Node()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely because the value type of your map is `pair<int const, Node>`, not `pair<int, Node>`: in a map, the key is *constant*.

Since `insert()` accepts a `pair<int const, Node> const&` and you supply a `pair<int, Node>`, to perform the conversion a temporary must be constructed from which the value in the map can in turn be copy-constructed.

To verify it, change this line:

```
pair<int, Node> toInsert = pair<int, Node>(2, node2);
```

Into this line:

```
pair<int const, Node> toInsert = pair<int const, Node>(2, node2);
```

And you should see the extra call to the copy constructor disappear.

Also keep in mind, that the concrete implementation of Standard Library containers are not required to perform a particular number of copies: implementations may vary, and different optimization levels could make things different as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `pair<int,Node>`.
The type taken by the insert method is `map<K,V>::value_type` which is defined as `pair<const K,V>`.
The compiler must insert an additional copy to convert between these two types.

Try using `map<int,Node>::value_type` instead of `pair<int,Node>`. It is better to use the types defined by the class itself rather than recreating them from scratch.

You can also avoid your first copy by writing.

```
map<int,Node>::value_type toInsert(2,node2);
```

instead of

```
map<int,Node>::value_type toInsert = map<int,Node>::value_type(2,node2);
```

Answer (score -1):

When you do the following:

```
toInsert = pair<int, Node>(2, node2);
```

You are passing the `node2` into the constructor of the `pair` object. Even though you are passing by reference, conceptually you are binding the *values* together, and that means the `pair` object is making a copy of the `node2` object. Copy #1.

When you pass this `pair` object to the insert function:

```
mapping.insert(toInsert);
```

.. yes you are passing by reference, but the container doesn't know anything about the lifetime of the object referenced (`toInsert`). So it makes it's own copy to store in the container. Copy #2.

Comment: Where is copy #3 in your explanation? OP's post shows one copy for toInsert (which you explained), and two copies for insert (of which you only explain one). Also, I don't think your explanation for the second part is correct. The reason that containers make copies and insert them is by design (i.e. they promise you to do that so that your object in the inserting scope lives on untouched), not because of lifetime reasons. If you don't want that, you can either use `emplace` or `std::move`.

Comment: Funny, it seems I misread the question. Well, I learned something from the accepted answer now as well. Oh well.