# How does an undefined new operator lead to undefined behaviour in C++?

Tags: c++, new-operator, heap-memory, copy-constructor, delete-operator

Here I have a C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Person {
    private:
        int year;
        Person(const Person& pers);
    public:
        Person(int y): year(y)
        { cout << "Default constructor" << endl;}

        ~Person()
        {
            cout << "Destructor " << endl;
        }

        int get_year() const
        {
            return year;
        }
};


int main()
{
    map<string, Person*> test;
    test.insert(pair<string, Person*>("ini_1", new Person(2)));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Default constructor
```

1. From the output, I would like to know, how I can delete the value of `test` map given `new Person(2)` without coding it like first

```
Person* per = new Person(2)
test.insert(pair<string, Person*>("ini_1", per));

delete per;
```

2. Without defining like this first

```
Person* per = new Person(2)
test.insert(pair<string, Person*>("ini_1", per));
```

Will it lead to undefined behaviour? Can you describe more detail of the undefined behaviour? Especially how does it exist in the memory? Thanks.

3. If it is not correct, can I do like this which use `Person` instead `new Person`? Will it lead to any undefined behaviour?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Person {
    private:
        int year;

    public:
        Person(int y): year(y)
        { cout << "constructor" << endl;}

        Person(const Person& pers)
        {
            cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
        }
        ~Person()
        {
            cout << "Destructor " << endl;
        }

        int get_year() const
        {
            return year;
        }
};


int main()
{
    map<string, Person> test;

    test.insert(pair<string, Person>("ini_1", Person(2)));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

4. I don't understand why the constructor ran for once and copy constructor ran for twice. Can you please explain where they happened?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: What do you mean by "defining" a pointer, here?

Comment: I don't see any undefined behavior here. In the pointer case your destructor doesn't run, but that's because there's no `delete`. You could correct that by using a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer. But there's nothing wrong here with using the values instead of pointers..

Comment: @wangmyde you cannot test Undefined Behavior, you have to know. And there is  not such thing in C++ as "new pointer" or "undefined pointer", you should use common terminology if you want to be understood.

Comment: On 4. You create the `Person` temporary, that gets copied to construct the `pair<>` temporary, and copied again into the insert function.

Comment: Please ask only one question

Comment: @user253751, I directly did `test.insert(pair<string, Person*>("ini_1", new Person(2)));` but not first `Person* per = new Person(2)` then `test.insert(pair<string, Person*>("ini_1", per));`

Comment: @wangmyde That is like doing `doSomething(2);` instead of `int i = 2; doSomething(i);` - i.e. it makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the map.insert() method invoke the copy constructor twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247262/why-does-the-map-insert-method-invoke-the-copy-constructor-twice).

Comment: One option would be to use smart pointers in your map, either std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr. This would ensure that the allocated Person objects are deleted when the map is destroyed, but they come with caveats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the output, I can see the destructor did not run. I would like to
>   know, how I can delete the new pointer without defining it?

You declared a map of ;pointers to Person

```
map<string, Person*> test;
```

So an object of the type Person is created only once in this statement

```
test.insert(pair<string, Person*>("ini_1", new Person(2)));
```

Further the map deals with the pointer not with the object.

You will need to delete the created object explicitly. For example

```
for ( auto &item : test )
{
    delete item.second;
     item.second = nullptr;
}
```

If you will not delete the allocated object (or objects) then there will be a memory leak.

> I don't understand why the constructor ran for once and copy
>   constructor ran for twice. Can you please explain where they happened?

In this statement

```
test.insert(pair<string, Person>("ini_1", Person(2)));
```

the conversion constructor is called explicitly to create an object of the type Person `Person(2)`.

Then the copy constructor of the class Person is called to create an object of the type `pair<string, Person>`.

And at last this object is copied to the map again calling the copy constructor of the type Person for the data member second of the pair.

So three objects were created and three destructors for the objects were invoked.

Comment: Hi, @Vlad from Moscow. If I use `test.insert(pair<string, Person*>("ini_1", new Person(2)));` but not `Person* per = new Person(2); test.insert(pair<string, Person*>("ini_1", per));`, will it lead to undefined behaviour? Like here as what @h0r53 said [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376783/how-is-the-process-for-a-desctructed-class-that-can-still-exist-in-a-map-contain?noredirect=1#comment104947343_59376783) `Using new will almost certainly cause issues...`

Comment: `Using new will almost certainly cause issues, because the Person object will be stored on heap allocated memory. 1) Unless you call delete on the object, you'll have a memory leak. 2) Even if you do delete the object, the heap memory it allocated will be available for reuse, while your map still points to that memory. This is even worse.`  Is that correct?

Comment: @wangmyde Neither undefined behavior will be in this case. The undefined behavior can occur if you will try to delete the memory two times using the locally declared pointer and the pointer stored in the map.